# removing part of a string

Tags: r, string

I have a `df` like below

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L,), 
                          class = "factor")), 
                    .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", 
                     row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I want to remove part of string in each cell after the first `|`

so the output looks like this

```
out<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("O15111", 
"P41250", "P62805", "Q13547", "Q16555", "Q8NBS9", "Q9H6T3"), class = "factor"), ta.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: This is extremely easy with `gsub`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through every column in `df` and substitute everything after first `|` with a blank space

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) sub("\\|.*", "", as.character(x)))

df
#   V1       V2        V3
#1 P62805   Q71DI3       
#2 P41250   P12081    P34896
#3 Q13547   P62805       
#4 O15111   Q13748       
#5 Q8NBS9   Q12792       
#6 Q16555   Q14195-2  P21359
#7 Q9H6T3   Q9Y230    Q9Y265
```

**EDIT**

As per the update in the comments, to paste the columns together and remove the values which are empty

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(sub("\\|.*", "", as.character(x[x!=""])), collapse = ","))

#[1] "P62805,Q71DI3"  "P41250,P12081,P34896"   "Q13547,P62805" "O15111,Q13748"         
#[5] "Q8NBS9,Q12792"  "Q16555,Q14195-2,P21359" "Q9H6T3,Q9Y230,Q9Y265"
```

Comment: Don't need to loop really, just `df[] <- sub("\\|.*", "", unlist(df))` should do

Comment: @Ronak Shah  how can you put each line together with a , seperated ?

Comment: @nik Do you need this ? `apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(sub("\\|.*", "", as.character(x)), collapse = ","))`

Comment: @Ronak Shah  yes but if I use that then it makes it like P62805,Q71DI3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, for example the first line. I want it to be P62805,Q71DI3

Comment: @nik ok, we need to exclude the empty strings then . How about `apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(sub("\\|.*", "", as.character(x[x!=""])), collapse = ","))` ?

Comment: @Ronak Shah thanks I accepted and liked your answer